# In Angular2 I need to show and hide child components from within a parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

**In Angular2 hows best to show and hide child components?**

I have **one parent component** and **three child components**.

By default **onInit** all child components need to be hidden.
And **childComponentA** needs to show onclick of a button in the parent component.

**The flow:**

I have a button in **childComponentA** that needs to show **childComponentB** on click and childComponentB component has a button that needs to show **childComponentC**. So like a flow of show and hides.

**Hows best to do this?**

**Possible solution?**

I was thinking of creating a service that all the child components subscribe to show and hide. But not sure if its the best solution.

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<section>
   <button (click)="showChildComponentA()"></button>

   <childComponentA></childComponentA>
   <childComponentB></childComponentB>
   <childComponentC></childComponentC>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your code clean and maintainable, and not have boolean flags all over the place, it would be best to use a service (maybe called `ToggleService`) which handles the toggling and checking of whether or not something should be shown.

For instance, here is a simple `ToggleService` that gives you the ability to create new items, remove the items, and toggle the visibility of the items with show/hide methods (keep in mind nothing below is tested, I literally just wrote it all on the fly for this question -- but it all seems logical and should work):

```
@Injectable()
export class ToggleService {
    toggleMap: {[uniqueKey: string]: any} = {};

    create(key: string) {
        this.toggleMap[key] = null;
    }

    remove(key: string) {
        delete this.toggleMap[key];
    }

    isShown(key: string): boolean {
        return this.toggleMap[key];
    }

    show(key: string) {
        this.toggleMap[key] = true;
    }

    hide(key: string) {
        this.toggleMap[key] = false;
    }
}
```

Now in your component, you can leverage the service:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(public toggleService: ToggleService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.toggleService.create('componentOne');
        this.toggleService.create('componentTwo');
        this.toggleService.create('componentThree');
    }

    // Clean up when parent component is destroyed to save memory
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.toggleService.remove('componentOne');
        this.toggleService.remove('componentTwo');
        this.toggleService.remove('componentThree');
    }
}
```

In the template:

```
<button (click)="toggleService.show('componentOne')">Show component 1</button>
<button (click)="toggleService.show('componentTwo')">Show component 2</button>
<button (click)="toggleService.show('componentThree')">Show component 3</button>

<componentOne *ngIf="toggleService.isShown('componentOne')"></componentOne>
<componentTwo *ngIf="toggleService.isShown('componentTwo')"></componentTwo>
<componentThree *ngIf="toggleService.isShown('componentThree')"></componentThree>
```

Bear in mind that clicking one of the buttons will not hide another button. For that, you may want to create a `toggle` method which will loop through the entire `toggleMap` in the service and make everything false, and then set only one thing to true.

I'll leave that last bit as an exercise for you ;)

Comment: Hi Lansana, I was thinking an observable subject would be better in a service with an object like this {childAVisible: true, etc }

Comment: An observable subject in the `ToggleService` would work equally as well here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with component based design. In my opinion, event driven design is not cool since it is hard to trace which component interacts with which event publisher.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyit96?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
<button (click)="changeFlag(CompFlags.Comp1)">Show comp1 </button>
<br>
<comp1 *ngIf="checkState(CompFlags.Comp1)"  (clicked)="changeFlag(CompFlags.Comp2)"></comp1>
<br>
<comp2  *ngIf="checkState(CompFlags.Comp2)" (clicked)="changeFlag(CompFlags.Comp3)"></comp2>
<br>
<comp3  *ngIf="checkState(CompFlags.Comp3)"></comp3>

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
}) 
export class AppComponent  {
  CompFlags = CompFlags;
  state = CompFlags.None;

  changeFlag(flag:CompFlags){
    (this.state & flag) ? this.state &= ~flag : this.state |= flag;
  }

  checkState(flag:CompFlags){
    return !!(this.state & flag);
  }
}

export enum CompFlags{
  None = 0,
  Comp1 = 1 << 0,
  Comp2 = 1 << 1,
  Comp3 = 1 << 2
}
```