# Angular 5 create multiple Instances of one Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a WebApp showing 3 virtual mobile devices at the same time.

Each device consists of a `mobile_container`.
I put my `mobile_container` in my root-component like this:

```html
<div>
  <app-mobile-container [fruit]="apple"></app-mobile-container>
  <app-mobile-container [fruit]="orange"></app-mobile-container>
  <app-mobile-container [fruit]="strawberry"></app-mobile-container>
</div>
```

`fruit` is an Inputt which says the container which data he needs to access and display. This works fine

I created a Service `toggleService` to toggle the different Views in on of the Containers this works great too.
It looks like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class ToggleService {
    constructor() {
    }
    tabs: { name: string, visibility: boolean }[] = [
        { "name": "MainView", "visibility": true },
        { "name": "DetailView", "visibility": false },
    ];
    
    changeTab(index: number) {
        //changes View for example to "DetailView"
    }
    goToPrevTab() {
        //changes View for example back to "MainView"
    }
}
```

But if i paste 3 `mobile_containers` and click for example the `DetailView`-Component it changes the View in all `mobile_containers` and not only in the clicked one. This is because every container shares the same `toggleService` with each other.

How can i tell my `mobile-containers` to create a `toggleService 1`, `toggleService 2`, `toggleService 3`. So that they don´t access the same `toggleView.tabs`?

Comment: The point of a service is to have a single instance

Comment: Ok, so how can i solve the described problem if a service isn´t the right solution?

Comment: The behavior that the HTML template should have should be defined solely by the **component**.

Comment: There is a solution. Basically what you have now is that your service is so called "singleton" - one shared across the app. You need to have separate instances of your service. Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/providers. Currently you define your provider at the root component level and it is available to all the components, you need to define it at the component level using in-component declaration

Comment: But I would agree with Adrien - ideally you would just define the desired behaviour within your components in your use case. At least I don't see how you really need multiple services.

Comment: Because an Service makes it easy for me. For example if i open my `DetailView` and this View also shows a Child i need many Emitters to Communicate between my `mobile-container` and all the child-childs. For Example i have a NavBar, which button-Visibility depends on the contents of my `mobile-container`

Comment: @After_8 I have posted an answer. it will give a hint about  how to create multiple object to a service. let me know is this useful to you?

Comment: Check my answer here and see if this solution works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797196/4749297

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Angular2 I need to show and hide child components from within a parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796976/in-angular2-i-need-to-show-and-hide-child-components-from-within-a-parent-compon)

Comment: Still struggling on that? If yes, can you post more details about the `app-mobile-container`? Like the code of the ts component behind it, for isntance. I'd like to propose a solution that doesn't require a service at all.

Comment: Problem is solved. It really was just to provide the service in my `mobile-container`. And NOT in the App_Module.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a question where do you PROVIDE the service, which determines where it is instanced. You can provide at a component level.  In the following example, ReportBindingService is instanced at the ReportContainer level.  The ReportBindingService is analagous to your ToggleServiced

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-container',
  templateUrl: './report-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report-container.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [ ReportBindingTreeService ]
})
```

Comment: Yes i provided my Service now in my Component and not in my App_module and it works just fine :)

Comment: How can I pass parameters into the service with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer from another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797196/4749297

That solution may work better for you as the `ToggleService` is independent of any one component or piece of logic and can be re-used accordingly. All you have to do is make your key names unique.

Here is the example code again:

```
@Injectable()
export class ToggleService {
    toggleMap: {[uniqueKey: string]: any} = {};

    create(key: string) {
        this.toggleMap[key] = null;
    }

    remove(key: string) {
        delete this.toggleMap[key];
    }

    isShown(key: string): boolean {
        return this.toggleMap[key];
    }

    show(key: string) {
        this.toggleMap[key] = true;
    }

    hide(key: string) {
        this.toggleMap[key] = false;
    }
}
```

Now in your component, you can leverage the service:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(public toggleService: ToggleService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.toggleService.create('componentOne');
        this.toggleService.create('componentTwo');
        this.toggleService.create('componentThree');
    }

    // Clean up when parent component is destroyed to save memory
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.toggleService.remove('componentOne');
        this.toggleService.remove('componentTwo');
        this.toggleService.remove('componentThree');
    }
}
```

In the template:

```
<button (click)="toggleService.show('componentOne')">Show component 1</button>
<button (click)="toggleService.show('componentTwo')">Show component 2</button>
<button (click)="toggleService.show('componentThree')">Show component 3</button>

<componentOne *ngIf="toggleService.isShown('componentOne')"></componentOne>
<componentTwo *ngIf="toggleService.isShown('componentTwo')"></componentTwo>
<componentThree *ngIf="toggleService.isShown('componentThree')"></componentThree>
```